# What is this exotic sounding scale?

Tags: theory, scales

> D E♭ F♯ G♯ A B♭ C♯

It's basically a double harmonic major/Byzantine scale with a raised 4th.

I don't know what to call it.

Comment: Is my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 6):

This is a Purvi thaat scale (also spelled Poorvi) from Indian classical music.
The ascending scale (Arohana) = S r G m P d N S+ (D Eb F# G# A Bb C# D#). Since the D# and Eb are enharmonic, we can describe this scale as being heptatonic. I advise using G# instead of Ab when you spell it.

Comment: Why the D# at the end?

Comment: @Richard Not all scales have seven tones like the Western diatonic "Major" scale. Some have five (pentatonic), some have six (whole tone) ... some have twelve (Western chromatic) ... there are tons of scale variations out there. Sometimes the direction matters. In this style of music, ascending scales sometimes differ from the descending pattern. On the way up they use D#. In Western music, the Melodic Minor scale used to differ up v. down but it has since widely been accepted to be the same in both directions.